# Flash object/embed breaks layout

Tags: css, flash, layout, embed

EDIT: I ended up resorting to `td { max-width: 460px; }`, which solved the immediate problem in both IE and FF. Still curious though about the cause of this layout behaviour.

I'm working on an existing page which uses a table layout of two columns. In a cell in the left one, there is an ordinary `<object><param /><param /><embed /></object>` snippet embedding a flash map (http://backspace.com/mapapp/):

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" id="zoom_map"  style="display: block !important;" height="251" width="460">
    <param name="movie" value="/[path]/world.swf?data_file=/[path]/data.xml">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
    <embed src="/[path]/world.swf?data_file=/[path]/data.xml" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="Clickable World Map" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" style="display: block !important;" title="Adobe Flash Player" align="top" height="251" width="460"> 
</object>
```

The problem is that in IE 9 and FF 21.0, even though both the object and the embed seem to be exactly the intended 460px wide when inspecting with Firebug or IE's dev tool, the table column becomes significantly wider. When using Firebug in FF to delete the embed, the map disappears but the layout does not change. When also deleting the object, the column shrinks to the indended width.

I read somewhere that `display: block` sometimes fixes issues like this, but that is already in place and doesn't seem to help. In Chrome everything is fine, i.e. there is no additional space to the right of the map.

I have tried setting the width in the style attribute. I have also tried wrapping the whole thing in a div with a width of 460px and overflow: hidden, but also to no avail.

I seem out of luck googling the issue so I'm hoping someone will be able to help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was just a case of me misunderstanding the automatic laying out of a table with the default `table-layout: auto`. It turned out that if I replaced the flash object with a div of the same width, the effect on the column width was exactly the same.

My conclusion is that the mere presence of an object with a fixed width in the left column made the layout engine adjust the balance between the two columns, even though it didn't really have to. Since the right column only contained paragraphs and headers etc. with no specified width, it was considered safe to steal some width from that column.